# Custom Layout for Single Product page - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a custom layout for one of our product pages in Woocommerce. I have searched and followed so many tutorials, but none are working for me. I copied 'single-product.php' and placed it into my active child theme in the folder 'woocommerce'. I then duplicated this and renamed it 'single-product-landing.php'.

I then placed the following code into my functions.php page:

```
add_filter( 'template_include',     'custom_single_product_template_include', 10 );

function custom_single_product_template_include( $template ) {
if ( is_product() && ( has_term( 'custom', 'product_cat') ) ) {
$template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product-landing.php';
 } 
return $template;
}
```

Then I tried changing items in single-product-landing.php but nothing is changing, so it can't be picking it up. To confirm, I have the product assigned to the 'custom' category.

I should also add that my product is a 'variable' product, am not sure if that has any affect on anything here.

EDIT: I have found the following code in my 'single.php' file - I think this may be interfering. Problem is, if I delete this nothing shows on any of my pages (even those not affected by the new template):

```
 <?php
      if(get_theme_mod('product_layout') == 'custom') {
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-custom' );
      } else {
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
      }
  ?>
```

Any idea how I can modify this to still have content show but not over-rule the template change that i'm trying to make?

Comment: you don't need a function to override a woocommerce template, simply copy the template to your child-theme/woocommerce and keep the name the same,

Comment: That will change all pages. I'm trying to create a custom layout for just ONE of my product pages.

Comment: I see, try renaming the template to  taxonomy-product_cat-Your_category_product_slug.php and put it back in the base of your child theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Page templates are loaded after the `template_filter` has been run, so adding that code to a page template file will have no effect. To make that run, place the same code in your child theme's `functions.php`.
2. The 566 at the end of the `add_filter` line refers to the filter's loading priority and not a category id. Simply put, the higher the number the later the filter will be loaded.
3. Finally, your `if` statement can be simplified a little using Woocommerce functions - `if ( is_product() && ( has_term( 'custom', 'product_cat') ) ) {` - doesn't make much difference, but it's tidier.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I moved it into functions.php, changed the '566' to 10, and updated that line but it's still not loading. Any other ideas what to try?

Comment: I edited my code above so you can see exactly what I have.

Comment: You've missed off the 'product_cat' in has_term - `if ( is_product() && ( has_term( 'custom', 'product_cat') ) ) {`. If it's still not working add `echo "hello"; die();` as the first line of the function. It will print "hello" to the page and then kill the script immediately, so you will at least know that the action is actually working.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The echo works, so something weird is happening in that it won't pick-up the template. I checked numerous times that it's in the correct folder (child theme - Woocommerce) and that it's spelt correctly. For some reason though it just won't pick it up. Is there anything that needs to be in that particular .php file? Other than the coding for the store page, of course.

Comment: I think I may have found the culprit - please see my edit above. Possibly this is the problem?

Comment: I managed to resolve it! It actually needed to be in the themes single-product.php file; adding it to the function was conflicting with the coding that was setup for some reason. I'll go ahead and mark your answer as correct since this will probably be the case for 95% of others.