# Custom product page layout by category ( Woocommerce )

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to php and Woocommerce. I know this question has already been asked but i can't figure out how to make it work ... Right now, i have 3 different categories on my Woocommerce shop ( i'm developping using Understrap ). I've created my basic product page layout, everything works fine. Now, i'd like to create a custom layout for my products that are in my "cleaning" category.

What i did for now is add this to my functions.php child theme :

```php
add_filter('template_include', 'cleaning_single_product_template_include', 10);

function cleaning_single_product_template_include($template)
{
    if (is_product() && (has_term('cleaning', 'product_cat'))) {
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product-cleaning.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Then i've created a `single-product-cleaning.php` file inside my woocommerce folder. For now, i've just pasted an `<h1>LOREM</h1>` to see if it shows up on the page, but it doesn't ..

Now in the code i've added to my `functions.php`, if i replace the content of my function with a simple

```
echo "test"; die();
```

It works, the "test" message appears on my cleaning product pages. But if i let the code i've written as is, then it just display the regular product page from single-product ... Any idea what i am missing here ?

EDIT : i've found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103732/custom-layout-for-single-product-page-woocommerce) on stackoverflow where he seems to have found a solution (see his last comment) but i don't understand what code he moved or how he solved it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed! For those having the same problem, i've just modified a little bit my `functions.php` function like this :

```php
add_filter('template_include', 'cleaning_single_product_template_include', 50, 1);

function cleaning_single_product_template_include($template)
{
    if (is_singular('product') && (has_term('cleaning', 'product_cat'))) {
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product-cleaning.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```